# (Javascript) Script won't count just once, perhaps not recognizing variable?

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm sure this is a super easy fix and I just can't see it.. 
I have a play button and I only want it to write to database (inc playcount) only when it's clicked the first time.

Any idea why this doesn't work? This result counts every click, and if I do if countonce = 0 and declare at beginning as 0 it won't count any clicks. Am I misunderstanding javascript?

```
 <div id="left-05-play_">
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var currsong = 1;
 var playcountadd = document.getElementById('left-05-play_');
 playcountadd.onclick = function() {
 if (countonce != 1) {
 $.post( "php/songadd.php", { addsong: "1", } );
 var countonce = 1;
 } }
 </script>
 </div>
```

Thank-you for taking the time to read this question.

Comment: move the var out of the function

Comment: I appreciate your comment, thank-you

Comment: i would also disable the button in the onclick to indicate to the user that further clicks will be ignored even with internet working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
var currsong = 1;
var songadded = false;
var playcountadd = document.getElementById('left-05-play_');

playcountadd.onclick = function() {
   if (!songadded) {
      $.post( "php/songadd.php", { addsong: "1", } );
      songadded = true;
   }
}
```

- Changed `countonce` to `songadded`
- Moved `songadded` out of `onclick` function
- Changed `songadded` to boolean logic
- Check whether `songadded=false` before proceeding with AJAX post

Comment: Thank-you so much curt! Worked beautifully of course and showed me something extremely valuable, can't thank-you enough!